# Why doesn't my question about a topic that hasn't been covered in pep 8 have more upvotes?

Tags: discussion

I asked this question,

[Should if statements be surrounded by blank lines to follow pep8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47105228/should-if-statements-be-surrounded-by-blank-lines-to-follow-pep8),

on stack overflow because I couldn't find anything that addressed blank lines around if statements and I wanted to write well formatted code. I spent a great deal of time looking for a answer to this question before asking SO. There wasn't an answer to this question that I could find even after combing through pep 8 for a while.

The question is well written and given the amount of garbage surrounding the subject of Pep8 on SO it should have a lot more upvotes. Two upvotes just seems a little bit too low. I was honestly expecting 5. Did I do something wrong or are 2 upvotes reasonable in this situation?

This question is not a duplicate because the focus of this question is what I'm doing wrong with my questions. The focus of the suggested duplicate question is why people aren't upvoting the questions they answer to increase the popularity of the question and get more reputation for answering it. This questions, while being related, are obviously different after a read through. I'm not looking for an explanation to a sub optimal behavior I'm seeing. I'm looking for a way to improve my own behavior to achieve a desired result. Not the same thing. Aside from the difference in focus, the answers to the two questions aren't even the same. The answers to the suggested duplicate all seem to indicate that one simply needs to ask a well researched question to get upvotes. The answers to this question indicate that one needs to go beyond that to get more upvotes. Only one person in the comment chain below this question has brought up the quality of research put into questions and that was in reference to another question I asked a question on meta about, not this question. Honestly that commentator's comments can probably be removed from this question since they're not all that relevant to this question in particular.

It has a -5 now so I guess I have my answer.

Comment: only 168 views over 4 months. 2 votes is not bad at all.

Comment: It has 2 upvotes and 0 downvotes. You got the answer you were looking for. I don't really know why you think that it should have more votes since that seems to be an above average score for the [tag:pep8]-tag. You only get votes over time when the question is something other people are actually searching for.

Comment: Why does this question have 4 down votes? This places is beyond confusing.

Comment: @Steve I would guess the downvoters did so because the question comes off as popularity whining. AKA "why don't people like what I post". Your question here might be better-received if you suggest why you think your question there should have more upvotes.

Comment: @TylerH I gave your suggestion a go, hopefully that helps.

Comment: @Steve That's a good first effort, I suppose, but it's still a little vague. Why do you think it should get 5 votes? Why not 4 or 6? Why not 0? Do questions in [tag:pep8] normally get that many upvotes? Does [tag:pep8] have many followers? Are there newer/lower quality questions with higher scores? etc.

Comment: "The question is well written" - I agree it's well written compared to all the other trash on the site. This is why the question hasn't been *downvoted*. If you want *upvotes*, you need to take it to the next level: Ask a question that *other* people need the answer to. Or ask a question that's interesting to drive-by viewers.

Comment: ^ On top of what Mysticial mentioned, your question got an accepted answer shortly after being asked. A lot of people browser tags and question pages looking for questions that don't have answers already, or at least don't have an accepted. By accepting an answer, you are signaling on the questions page that "this question is answered; only come here if you have this problem and need the answer"

Comment: @Mystical could you leave that in answer form for this question?

Comment: As a sidenote, asking a meta question about each and every question you've asked is going to get super old, super fast.

Comment: @fbueckert I'm already tired of this, but I'm more tired of having poorly received questions for no communicated reason.

Comment: You do have a communicated reason; the same one everyone else gets; "This question does not show research effort; it is not clear or useful."

Comment: @fbueckert I think he means on main.

Comment: @TylerH That...is the reason on main.  Isn't it?

Comment: @fbueckert I assumed he just meant this question, which was positively scored. I guess it could mean his previous ones too, which appear to be overall negatively scored

Comment: @TylerH One of his first introductions to meta was the classic, "Why am I unable to ask any more questions?"  So, the fact that his questions are not well received is basically a given at this point.

Comment: @fbueckert That's the least descriptive shit anyone has ever read. All I'm doing here is clarifying that. I usually do a bunch of research before I ask questions. SO is usually the last place I ask. I don't really need to use this website though. If I'm having a really bad problem I ask questions in better places. SO is just an easy way to signal things to employers so I'm planning on either just deleting my account here or making a second account and asking popular questions to get loads of reputation.

Comment: Well, I can't stop you from trying, but for all your previous bravado, I don't think you know nearly enough about how to avoid the system generated ban.  All I can say is that's a really bad idea, and active attempts to circumvent it generally end badly.  As for the initial statement, if you have researched, then perhaps it's a good idea to *show* said research.

Comment: @fbueckert so include links to sites that don't answer my question!? You're right about the sock puppet thing. I won't do that.

Comment: No, *show your research*.  Show what you found, what it did, and why it doesn't work for you.  That's literally the basis of showing effort.

Comment: @fbueckert isn't that the code I executed and the error message and traceback? Are you still on that time I didn't know how to debug code that had a ton of different files involved?

Comment: @TylerH that guy is asking why people don't upvote questions they answer. It's less of a "what am I doing wrong?" question and more of a "why aren't people meta gaming harder?" question.

Comment: @Steve The answers still apply; it's a general "why aren't decent questions upvoted" question. Yours is simply a specific "why isn't *my* decent question upvoted" question. That's exactly how dupes are supposed to operate.

Comment: @TylerH It's a specific question asking about a behavior people and doing. You're making it general for no reason. Aside from that the answers for this question in particular are different. marking this question as a low quality duplicate will just delete all of the usefulness of this question that isn't in that other question. The why isn't my decent question upvoted bit that you've added in there is just from the title. Once you read my question you can clearly see that it's a meta-cognition focused question about the level of upvotes this question deserves to be at.

Comment: @Steve duplicates are not low quality, duplicates are duplicates. The bottom line is your question doesn't *deserve* to be at any particular score. It gets the score it gets based on how people feel when they see the title and/or body. Your best bet is to rid yourself permanently of the notion that your (or anyone's) questions *deserve* anything at all.

Comment: @TylerH That's just not consistent with what I've observed on SO. I honestly suspect that I am just pissing people off. I ran across a question yesterday that is nearly identical to one of mine with a ton of down votes. The question I found is sitting at 0 votes for some reason. I'm starting to wonder if my question got more views than his for some reason. That's unrelated though. Also, this question is low quality according the number of votes it has, so making it a duplicate would make it a low quality duplicate. I'm worried that this question will be deleted.

Comment: @Steve Well, you can see how many views a question has. As for deletion, you can prevent automatic deletion for sure by accepting Mysticial's answer. There's nothing you can do to avoid users manually voting to close or delete your question though (as you may know already). At any rate, votes on meta work differently. Downvotes don't mean "low quality" necessarily; they typically mean "I disagree with this post or don't think it is a good idea". Despite all the edits you've made, you're still not really addressing *why*, objectively, based on the question's content, that it deserves so many ^s

Comment: @Steve Many of my questions have been around for *years* but they only have 1 to 3 upvotes (in fact my very first question, which I joined in order to ask, is at a score of 0 currently). It's not a matter of quality, it's an organic thing. If you keep posting high quality, answerable questions, then they will get upvoted. If you post common questions, they will get upvoted continuously over time. Other than that there isn't really any expectation to have. Certainly not a fixed (or even general) amount of upvotes in your mind that you feel your question should have.

Comment: I don't upvote good questions because I've forgotten how to do it:(

Comment: @Steve re "I honestly suspect that I am just pissing people off." However tempting it might be to take stuff personally, it's not about you. While you are probably a unique individual, you don't have that much importance in people's lives that they take time to downvote your posts, or be angry at you. That will come out rude, but you "don't matter". None of us does. All the interactions here could very well be anonymous.

Answer (score 19):

Looking at your question history I can see that you've struggled in the past with asking questions.

So I would like to congratulate you on finally being able to ask a decent question that is positively accepted and has gathered upvotes. We wish all users who struggle this way can improve like this.

---

However, digging yourself out of a hole is still a long-shot from being "popular" and getting a lot of upvotes.

Asking a well-formed and well-researched question will help avoid attracting the downvotes and close votes which are used to clean out all the trash. But to attract upvotes, you need to go a step further.

That is, you need to ask a question that falls into one of these categories:

- Useful to *other* people who may looking for an answer to the same question.
- Is "interesting" to drive-by viewers who casually come across your question.

Comment: It's at -5 I give up.

Comment: It's at -5 now because of all the negative attention from this meta question. Normally that won't happen. If you ask an ok question, you won't get downvoted like this. In this case, it was borderline. Reading through the comments above, it seems that you've ticked off a bunch of people who (presumably) proceeded to downvote your question as punishment. This isn't how things are supposed to work. But it is what it is.

Comment: Rofl right after someone tells me I'm not important enough to do that. So my pep 8 question wasn't even good to begin with. Shouldn't take so long for someone to tell me this.

Comment: @Steve I haven’t downvoted your PEP8 question or this Meta-question about it, but I can tell you it’s almost always counterproductive to either ask for upvotes on a question or complain about downvotes on a question. To Meta, those questions seem self-serving or wheedling, and usually such Meta-Qs have the exact opposite of the intended effect.

Comment: @DanBron I honestly don't think that matters at this point. I'm still going to ask questions about all of my questions before leaving. If nothing else I can learn more about effective communication. When it comes right down to it, SO doesn't do what I need it to do. It's time to find a different product.

Comment: @Steve You aren't gonna want to hear this. But the longer this drags on, the more your attitude says that you still haven't "gotten it" - and you're getting downvoted for it. You managed to get lucky once which avoided downvotes until you brought it here to meta. You're still with the masses of people who abuse the system and refuse to learn. If you think you can continue to "ask all your questions before leaving", you'll be mildly amused once you hit the question ban. And it will be even more amusing once you try to circumvent it. I wish you luck in your future endeavors.

Comment: @Mysticial I'm not going to circumvent it. I'm going to leave. I don't really care what my attitude says. There's no way to improve this situation in a timely fashion. I'm done with this product. If I can't ask questions again on meta then I'll leave. How did you not get that from my last paragraph?????????

Comment: @Steve Good. Then please leave. The site is *designed* to make abusive and unwanted users leave. It's better for us, it's better for them.

Comment: @Mysticial FYI: The user is *already* in the question ban.  He means asking a meta question about each and every question he's asked on main.  Because...that will help?

Comment: @Mysticial Wow you're right I should stay and contribute I've never thought of it that way.